# How to get the right file path in Servlet program?

Tags: java, file, servlets

I am trying to read xml and txt file using relative path, 
I tried   `getServletContext().getContextPath();`
but it gets the path in a wrong way 
for example

My file path is :

> D:\dev\workspace\Simulater\src\resources\Map.xml

Now when I apply,

```
System.out.println(getServletContext().getContextPath());
```

I get as an output:

> /Simulater

and when i apply :

```
File myTestFile= new File(Api.CONTEXT_PATH+fileName);
String path = myTestFile.getAbsoluteFile().toString();
System.out.println(path);
```

i get `D:\Simulater\src\resources\Map.xml`

an it is a wrong path since it dose not contains

> :\dev\workspace\

it seams like java takes the project name and add the driver that contains it

so dose any one can provide any help to get the right path

thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` to get full path `D:\dev\workspace\Simulater\src\resources\` then you can read file by giving this full path and  file name.

Comment: @MCEmperor he is not getting path what he is expecting. So it will give actual path that can be used to read file.

Comment: Another useful method is [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) (on `ServletContext`, not on `class` as *fdumay* suggested in a different answer).

Answer (score 0):

To read a file you nead to open an InputStream, as your file is in your classpath you can open the stream with the following statement :

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Map.xml");
```